# Table only shows 2 total results but instead shows 4 results = 2 duplicates?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$get_comment = $dbh->query("SELECT sc.sc_content, sc.sc_sid, sc.sc_date, m.username FROM schedule_comments AS sc LEFT JOIN members AS m ON sc.sc_uid = m.uid WHERE sc.sc_sid = '$view'");
```

Right there is my query to get a members username so that it can display... BUT INSTEAD.

It duplicates my results, here's a screenshot below.

http://i.gyazo.com/4d0ab0a354bb36294afe17c8c5efd2c3.png

As you can tell, the date these rows were inserted are the exact same. Only 2 rows are different.

I don't think there's anything wrong with this query, I think it's correct. What am  I doing wrong here?

Comment: what yo want exactly ?! do you want results without duplicate ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `DISTINCT` keyword to your query:

```
$get_comment = $dbh->query("SELECT DISTINCT sc.sc_content, sc.sc_sid, sc.sc_date, m.username FROM schedule_comments AS sc LEFT JOIN members AS m ON sc.sc_uid = m.uid WHERE sc.sc_sid = '$view'");
```

It should return only, well, distinct results :-)

Comment: That actually worked but now when other users post... It will post for each user.

So let's say someone said "I'm cool" well every user on the site appearantly has said "i'm cool" even though only one person said it...

Comment: It's a bit difficult to figure out exactly what's wrong without a database schema. Can you update your question with the schema for the tables involved in the query and a description of what you're trying to achieve?